# UE4 - Include Experimental Engine Plugins

Tags: plugins, reference, include, unreal-engine4

I try to have a reference to the int CurrentFrameCount within Scene Capturer contain into StereoPanorama Plugin.

To achieve so, I make this

```cpp
TSharedPtr<FStereoPanoramaManager> StereoSharedPtr = FStereoPanoramaModule::Get();
FStereoPanoramaManager* StereoPanoramaManager =  StereoSharedPtr.Get();

if (StereoPanoramaManager == NULL)
{
   return -1;
}

return StereoPanoramaManager->SceneCapturer->CurrentFrameCount;
```

I get a  fatal error LNK2019.

What I did try :

```cpp
- #include "../Plugins/Experimental/StereoPanorama/Source/StereoPanorama/Private/StereoPanoramaManager.h"
- [Public/Private]DependencyModuleNames.AddRange [...], "StereoPanorama"
- PublicIncludePaths.Add("../Plugins/Experimental/StereoPanorama/Source/StereoPanorama/Public/");
- #include "StereoPanorama.h"
```

Nothing works. However I did the same with another plugin (OnlineError.h) and it works as expected.

Do you know why I can't reference Experimental Plugins ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Probably you’ve not referenced the plugin as a dependency in your module’s build .cs file. There’s also the possibility that whatever you’re trying to reference hasn’t been exposed for other modules to see.

Comment: How may I référence a not exposed module ?